# Unknown error when registering new user using firebase - code did not change

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I had been able to create a new user to firebase and i have 2 created. i havent changed the code but for some reason i keep getting my sign up error message when i create a new user. i can still successfully log in with the users i already created so i dont think it is a connection problem.

Register new user method:

```
mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);
                            current_user_db.setValue(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Log cat error that appears directly after register user button pressed:

```
01-28 15:34:19.562 7070-7115/? D/SensorService: [SO] -0.194 9.187 4.067
01-28 15:34:22.872 7070-7115/? D/SensorService: [SO] -0.330 9.248 3.616
01-28 15:34:25.082 7070-7492/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2035 [01-28 15:34:25.093]
01-28 15:34:25.202 7070-7177/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.1179 ] when=72287837992000
01-28 15:34:25.202 7070-7176/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (7290): action: 0x4, toolType: 1
01-28 15:34:25.202 7070-7176/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (3423): action: 0x0, toolType: 1
01-28 15:34:25.202 3423-3423/com.example.alannalucas.travelfyp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
01-28 15:34:25.272 7070-7177/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=72287915497000
01-28 15:34:25.272 7070-7176/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (3423): action: 0x1, toolType: 1
01-28 15:34:25.282 3423-3423/com.example.alannalucas.travelfyp W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@7638104
01-28 15:34:25.292 7070-7238/? D/ActivityManager: startService callerProcessName:com.google.android.gms, calleePkgName: com.google.android.gms
01-28 15:34:25.292 7070-7238/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = com.google.android.gms/com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.service.FirebaseAuthService; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
01-28 15:34:25.302 7070-11959/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = null; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
01-28 15:34:25.312 31979-31979/? D/ContextImpl: ContextImpl running for user UserHandle{0} 0
01-28 15:34:25.312 7070-9141/? D/ActivityManager: startService callerProcessName:com.google.android.gms, calleePkgName: com.google.android.gms
01-28 15:34:25.312 7070-9141/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.proxy.AuthService; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
01-28 15:34:25.322 31979-20399/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyBAHKi9_QbJiJseaRKPVLgUdJmgSAF1Qb8, method: 1 ]
01-28 15:34:25.322 7070-7730/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = null; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
01-28 15:34:25.332 17225-17225/? D/ContextImpl: ContextImpl running for user UserHandle{0} 0
01-28 15:34:25.342 7070-11959/? D/ActivityManager: bindService callerProcessName:com.google.android.gms, calleePkgName: com.google.android.gms, action: null
01-28 15:34:25.342 7070-11959/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.gcm.http.GoogleHttpService; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
01-28 15:34:25.342 17225-17225/? D/ContextImpl: ContextImpl running for user UserHandle{0} 0
01-28 15:34:25.352 31979-677/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
01-28 15:34:25.352 6761-7093/? D/EnterpriseController: mIsMarkChainAdded is 0 mIsBlockChainAdded is 0 netId is 0
01-28 15:34:25.352 6761-7093/? D/Netd: getNetworkForDns: using netid 502 for uid 10006
01-28 15:34:25.392 31979-677/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 80 with tag 3000100400000000{805310468,0} for uid 10006, pid: 31979, getuid(): 10006
01-28 15:34:25.422 31979-677/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
01-28 15:34:25.422 31979-677/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14799007@14.7.99 (020304-223214910):2)
01-28 15:34:25.422 31979-677/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14799007@14.7.99 (020304-223214910):2)
01-28 15:34:25.442 31979-677/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
01-28 15:34:25.442 31979-677/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14799007@14.7.99 (020304-223214910):2)
01-28 15:34:25.442 31979-677/? W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@14799007@14.7.99 (020304-223214910):2)
01-28 15:34:25.832 31979-677/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 80
01-28 15:34:25.832 31979-677/? E/Volley: [6928] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyBAHKi9_QbJiJseaRKPVLgUdJmgSAF1Qb8
01-28 15:34:25.832 31979-20399/? I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: INVALID_EMAIL
01-28 15:34:25.842 31979-20399/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
01-28 15:34:25.842 31979-20399/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
01-28 15:34:25.852 7070-7238/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 15 selection = getToastGravityEnabledState
01-28 15:34:25.852 7070-7238/? D/SecContentProvider2: mCursor = null
01-28 15:34:25.852 7070-9615/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 15 selection = getToastGravity
01-28 15:34:25.852 7070-9615/? D/SecContentProvider2: mCursor = null
01-28 15:34:25.852 7070-11959/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 15 selection = getToastGravityXOffset
01-28 15:34:25.852 7070-11959/? D/SecContentProvider2: mCursor = null
01-28 15:34:25.862 7070-7333/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 15 selection = getToastGravityYOffset
01-28 15:34:25.862 7070-7333/? D/SecContentProvider2: mCursor = null
01-28 15:34:25.862 7070-7087/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 15 selection = getToastEnabledState
01-28 15:34:25.862 7070-7087/? D/SecContentProvider2: mCursor = null
01-28 15:34:25.872 7070-9141/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 15 selection = getToastShowPackageNameState
01-28 15:34:25.872 7070-9141/? D/SecContentProvider2: mCursor = null
01-28 15:34:25.902 2475-2475/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=517 createSurf (1x1),1 flag=4, Uoast
01-28 15:34:25.912 7070-9521/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] acquire WakeLock flags=0x2000000a tag=WindowManager uid=1000 pid=7070
01-28 15:34:25.992 7290-7290/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f0202d8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3 mobileLabel=Emergency calls only wifiLabel="VM0280939" emergencyOnly=true combinedLabel="VM0280939" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020291/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020096/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020291/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mQSDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0202d8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f0200ab/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_wifi_3 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f0202ac/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0202b9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
01-28 15:34:25.992 7290-7290/? D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton: onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:"VM0280939"
01-28 15:34:26.162 7070-7115/? D/SensorService: [SO] -0.461 9.564 3.190
01-28 15:34:26.992 7290-7290/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f0202d8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3 mobileLabel=Emergency calls only wifiLabel="VM0280939" emergencyOnly=true combinedLabel="VM0280939" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020291/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020096/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020291/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mQSDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0202d8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f0200ab/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_wifi_3 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f0202af/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_no_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0202b9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
01-28 15:34:26.992 7290-7290/? D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton: onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:"VM0280939"
01-28 15:34:27.762 7070-7238/? D/BatteryService: !@BatteryListener : batteryPropertiesChanged!
01-28 15:34:27.762 7070-7238/? D/BatteryService: level:100, scale:100, status:5, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4338, temperature: 290, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, POGO powered:false, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303201, invalid charger:0
01-28 15:34:27.762 7070-7238/? D/BatteryService: online:4, current avg:0, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:260000, current_now:84
01-28 15:34:27.762 7070-7070/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
01-28 15:34:27.772 7290-7290/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
01-28 15:34:27.772 7290-7290/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
01-28 15:34:27.772 7290-7290/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:100 status:5 health:2
01-28 15:34:27.772 3480-3480/? D/WidgetProviderAssistiveLight: onReceive() PLUG:2 / STATUS:5 / LEVEL:100
01-28 15:34:27.772 3480-3480/? D/WidgetProviderAssistiveLight: onReceive() mBatteryLevel : 100 / Static Battery Level : 100
01-28 15:34:27.772 3480-3480/? D/WidgetProviderAssistiveLight: getWidgetMode : false
01-28 15:34:27.792 7290-7290/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:100 status:5 health:2
01-28 15:34:27.792 7290-7290/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:100 status:5 health:2
01-28 15:34:27.892 7070-7712/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] [s] userActivity : event: 0 flags: 0 (uid: 1000 pid: 7070) eventTime = 72290534
01-28 15:34:27.892 7070-7712/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] release WakeLock flags=0x2000000a tag=WindowManager uid=1000 pid=7070 (0x0)
01-28 15:34:27.892 7070-7712/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] applyWakeLockFlagsOnReleaseLocked : userActivityNoUpdateLocked is called : SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK        'WindowManager' ON_AFTER_RELEASE (uid=1000, pid=7070, ws=WorkSource{10132}) (elapsedTime=1977)
01-28 15:34:28.432 2475-4358/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=517 Removed Uoast (9/9)
01-28 15:34:28.432 2475-2590/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=517 Removed Uoast (-2/9)
01-28 15:34:29.032 7070-9045/? D/SSRM:n: SIOP:: AP = 350
01-28 15:34:29.472 7070-7115/? D/SensorService: [SO] -1.232 8.637 6.078
01-28 15:34:31.002 7290-7290/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f0202d8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3 mobileLabel=Emergency calls only wifiLabel="VM0280939" emergencyOnly=true combinedLabel="VM0280939" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020291/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020096/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020291/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mQSDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0202d8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f0200ab/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_wifi_3 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f0202ac/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0202b9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
01-28 15:34:31.002 7290-7290/? D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton: onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:"VM0280939"
01-28 15:34:32.012 7290-7290/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f0202d8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3 mobileLabel=Emergency calls only wifiLabel="VM0280939" emergencyOnly=true combinedLabel="VM0280939" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020291/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020096/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020291/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mQSDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0202d8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f0200ab/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_wifi_3 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f0202af/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_no_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0202b9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
01-28 15:34:32.012 7290-7290/? D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton: onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:"VM0280939"
01-28 15:34:32.772 7070-7115/? D/SensorService: [SO] -1.298 8.867 4.494
01-28 15:34:36.072 7070-7115/? D/SensorService: [SO] -1.267 8.812 4.515
01-28 15:34:36.702 7290-7290/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 12 0 -12 -200 -12 -200 -1 0 2147483647 2147483647 -200 0 2147483647 0x3 gsm|lte
01-28 15:34:36.702 7290-7290/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=3
01-28 15:34:36.702 7290-7290/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength, No signal level. mPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mContentDescriptionPhoneSignal = Phone three bars.
```

Comment: The logcat contains this error "Error description received from server: INVALID_EMAIL". So it looks like you're entering an invalid email address.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right email?